# Jupyter cannot start, "ImportError: This package should not be accessible"

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I am unable to start a Jupyter notebook server on a linux machine. When I type `jupyter notebook`, I get the following errors:

```
ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse'
```

Here is some system info, let me know if anything else might be helpful:

```
$ jupyter --version
4.4.0

$ which jupyter
/usr/bin/jupyter

$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"

$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.15.0-38-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-023) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 10 10:59:38 UTC 2018

$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

When I try `python2 -m pip install urlparse --user`, I get an error: `Collecting urlparse Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement`

The reported error resembles [the one shown here](https://community.lsst.org/t/running-jupyter-notebook-existing-python-3-5-interferes/2152), but the stated solution of creating and using a python3 virtual environment doesn't seem to immediately fix the `jupyter notebook` command, although it does replace `python` and `python3` executable with links to the virtual environment:

```
(env) $ which jupyter
/usr/bin/jupyter
(env) $ which python
/home/.../env/bin/python
(env) $ which python3
/home/.../env/bin/python3
```

In case there is some question about the python path, here is the path for python 2:

```
$ ipython
...
In [2]: sys.path
Out[2]: 
['/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/$USER/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/home/$USER/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/$USER/.ipython']
```

And for python3

```
$ ipython3
...
In [2]: sys.path                                                                                                                                 
Out[2]: 
['/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/home/$USER/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/home/$USER/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/$USER/.ipython']
```

The full stack trace of the first error when starting Jupyter is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 18, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlretrieve
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/home/$USER/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/http/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '
ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted.
```

The contents of `/usr/bin/jupyter` are as follows:

```
$ cat `which jupyter`
#!/usr/bin/python3
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'jupyter-core==4.4.0','console_scripts','jupyter'
__requires__ = 'jupyter-core==4.4.0'
import re
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('jupyter-core==4.4.0', 'console_scripts', 'jupyter')()
    )
```

One suggested answer is that there is a spurious `http` library, "*it happens to be overridden by some 3rd-party module "http" at /home/$USER/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/http*". When I remove this library manually, I now get an error importing the `site` module, as follows:

```
$ cd /home/$USER/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
$ mv ./http ~/Desktop/python_disabled/python3/
$ jupyter notebook
Error processing line 1 of /home/$USER/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lazr.restfulclient-0.14.0-py3.6-nspkg.pth:

Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 174, in addpackage
    exec(line)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/types.py", line 171, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from reprlib import recursive_repr as _recursive_repr
  File "/home/$USER/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reprlib/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '
ImportError: This package should not be accessible on Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted.
```

Comment: What's your jupyter version? this is because the urlparse in Python 2.7.11 was renamed to urllib.parse in Python 3.

Comment: Thank you for the help! When I try `python2 -m pip install urlparse --user`, I get an error: `Collecting urlparse Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement`

Comment: Thanks! `$ jupyter --version` gives `4.4.0`; updated question with this info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keras import error Nadam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809686/keras-import-error-nadam)

Comment: What about `which jupyter` and `which python`? Are they both pointing to a python 3 install, or are they mismatched or anything?

Comment: Thanks @MattMessersmith! by default `jupyter`, `python`, and `python3` are in `/usr/bin`; if the virtual environment is loaded, then the python executables link to the virtual environment. I've updated the question with this new info.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I wasn't able to immediately see a connection with `jupyter` failing to launch due to `urllib`, and the failed import for `keras` in that question, but I have updated the question to include the python path as seen from inside python2 and python3 on my system.

Comment: We need to see the full traceback for that exception ...

Comment: @o11c, I know, I'm sorry, Stackoverflow wouldn't let me include the full traceback as it says that the post would then "include too much code"

Comment: @o11c, ok it seems to let one edit-in the full traceback after the fact. (now added at end of post)

Comment: What is the shebang in `/usr/bin/jupyter`?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Thanks! it is `#!/usr/bin/python3`, I've updated the question to include the contents of `/usr/bin/jupyter` for more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is wrong:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/home/$USER/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/http/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise ImportError('This package should not be accessible on Python 3. '
```

A standard module tries to import `http.client`, also [a standard module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/http/client.py). And in your installation, it happens to be overridden by some 3rd-party module "`http`" at `/home/$USER/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/http`.

Remove that 3rd-party module.

---

Judging by the same problem with `reprlib` package after uninstalling `http` in your updated question, you seem to have [the `micropython-lib` set of packages](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib) installed in `/home/$USER/.local/lib/python3.6`. **Since there are lots of them, it's easier to just delete the entire directory.** I've no idea how they ended up there since they are not only incompatible with a regular CPython installation but with Python 3 in general.

---

Finally, note that [depending on your needs, using `virtualenv` may be a more manageable solution than `pip --user`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153178/is-using-the-pip-user-option-as-safe-as-creating-a-virtualenv)

Comment: I'm not sure; The base python was installed via `apt` and all subsequent packages installed using `pip3 --user`. When I remove the `http` module, I now get an error `Failed to import the site module`, which I've added to the question.

Comment: @MRule the same problem with `reprlib` package. [You seem to have the `micropython-lib` set of packages installed in `/home/$USER/.local/lib/python3.6`](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib) which is incompatible with regular Python. Just delete the entire directory.

Comment: @MRule also note that [when using `--user`, you can end up with packages/package versions conflicting with system-wide ones if you don't keep these two sets in agreement manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51816639/setup-py-egg-info-error-code-3221225477/51817869#51817869).

Comment: Ok, this seems to have fixed it. Thank you so much! I needed to reinstall `matplotlib` and other libraries after removing that directory, but things are working now, it seems.

Comment: Would it be possible to update your answer in light of the more recent comments?

Comment: @MRule I already did. The comment about `--user` is but a side note, though I added a relevant link anyway.